# How to convert a 160 bit long bitset to a base 10 integer in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a 160 bit long bitset and I want to convert it to a base 10 number and use it in arithmetic operations.What type could I use to store that thing and how could I convert the bitset to base 10 to store it there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do?  Are you dealing with 160 bit numbers?  If not, can you explain what numbers you are expecting to get from your bit set?

Comment: Conversion from binary to decimal is far from trivial. Essentially you have to implement division.

Comment: These bits are the result of an sha-1 hash function.I am trying to use double hashing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) ,a hashing technique ,and I have to convert that huge binary number to decimal in order to use it in arithmetic operations.

Comment: Have you looked at one of the bigint libraries?

Comment: @Range: why do you have to convert it to decimal to use it in arithmetic operations? What are you passing it into, that will take a decimal string but not binary?

Comment: Well ,you are right ,I just need to do the multiplication and the addition ,it doesn't have to be decimal.You think I should do it in binary form?

Comment: @Range: yes, 160 bits will fit into three `unsigned long long` values. So put 64 bits into each (well, you only need to put 32 in the last) and base your final hashes on those. In fact, if you only need double hashing then you could quite reasonably use the top 64 bits of the SHA-1 hash as the first, and the bottom 64 bits as the second, and you're done. Basically, SHA-1 is already massive overkill for a hashtable, so you shouldn't need to do much more work.

Comment: Thanks to all of you people!I decided to use the code this guy posted (http://alikhuram.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/performing-arithmetic-on-bitsets-in-c/) to do the arithmeic operations in binary format.

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a 160-bit integer (there are quite a few arbitrary precision integer packages around to help with this).

Then do the following:

1. take the remainder from division by 10 to get the least significant decimal digit.
2. Divide the number by 10 (using integer division) to remove that least significant digit

Repeat until the result after dividing is 0. You now have the decimal digits of the number.

Comment: Although I'm willing to guess that whatever integer package you're using to store it will also do that conversion to base 10 for you.

Comment: I have a feeling that if the OP starts using a bignum library, then there would be no reason to have used bitset in the first place.

Comment: I don't have a problem with using external libraries ,as long as I can import them into ns-3 discrete network simulator ,which is a pain sometimes.

Comment: Your processor isn't going to store 160 bits in a register at once, so  all of your operations need to be broken down into smaller chunks.  The point of the external libraries is to do that for you, as doing it for yourself will not be fun.  Converting from binary to decimal seems  like a bit of an odd requirement to me, as you can't store decimal in digital computer.  You can store a decimal number as a string, or in BCD, but neither of these make doing operations on the number make it any easier.

Comment: Thanks to all of you people!I decided to use the code this guy posted (alikhuram.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/…) to do the arithmeic operations in binary format.